# What is value field of @ColumnDefault in jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I am not native.

I needed to use default value in jpa.I referenced [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value) and then I used @ColumnDefault.
It works good.But I want to know role of value field  of @ColumnDefault. comment of value of @ColumnDefault

> The DEFAULT definition to apply to the DDL.

But I don't know what means DEFAULT definition?
Even if I use @ColumnDefault("5000"), It is not applied 5000 only is applied default value 1000 of DDL.

What is role of value field of @ColumnDefault?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`DEFAULT` definition just mean the SQL default value for a column which can be defined by following DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Person (
  name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'N/A'
)
```

The value **'N/A'** is the default definition for the column name , which is equivalent to the following mapping :

```java
@Entity(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Column("name")
    @ColumnDefault("'N/A'")
    private String name;

}
```

`@ColumnDefault` is only useful when you use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to let hibernate to auto create/update your DB schema. If you do not use such auto-schema generation feature, it will not have any effect.

Comment: +1 for `@ColumnDefault is only useful when you use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to let hibernate to auto create/update your DB schema.`